# Facing problem in python dictionary operation

Tags: python, dictionary

I was trying to check whether the key **c_val** is available in the dictionary **mydic** or not. The problem is the if condition never returns true even when there are some keys equal to **c_val**.

```
  c_val = target - x[4]
    for c, v in mydic.items():
     if c_val == c:
        print(mydic.get(c))
```

Comment: What is `c`? What is `c_val`? There is not enough details in the question to attempt an answer. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I agree with @rdas. If I had to guess though then I think you have your dictionary keys as strings and your c_val is a numeric value, which is why they are never equal.

Comment: Probably one is a number and the other is a string. Anyway, you should _not_ iterate the values in the dict to see if some key is present, instead just use `if c_val in mydic: print(mydic[c_val])`. Also, there can never be "some keys equal to `c_val`" but at most one, otherwise there'd be duplicate keys in the dict.

Comment: Or did you actually want to compare to the `values` in the dict? Then it would make sense to use a loop, and you could have "some [values] equal to `c_val`". In this case, you have to check `if c_val == v`.